# Why can't I call operator() on temporary objects directly?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, operator-keyword

What I want to do can be summarized into the following code:

```
struct A{};

struct B{
    A& a;
    B(A& a) noexcept : a(a){}
    int operator()(int) {}
};

int main(){
    A a;
    B(a)(2);
}
```

And my compiler `(g++ 6)` rejected the code complaining that `a` shadows a parameter. However, if I try to explicitly call `operator()`, it works as expected.

It seems that `g++` will ignore the parentheses and see the statement as a declaration.

Is this the specified or expected behavior?

Comment: Be an angel and include an `int main()` ;-)

Comment: @Bathsheba, compile with `-S` is enough to get the result XD

Comment: It's fine; someone above my pay grade has answered correctly. (But I will upvote the question if you supply a `main`).

Comment: @Bathsheba, To be honest, this is extracted from my existing code, which is a shared library, so really wanted to do nothing in main...

Comment: @YiFei Sure, but it's still best to provide one in your question so we can just copy-paste and test your code.

Comment: @TartanLlama Then alright, rewrote `f` as main. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Have an upvote!

Comment: @Bathsheba "Above my paygrade" I wouldn't be so sure of that..

Comment: Me neither! [filler]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is one of those icky parsing rules which catches you every now and again. As you suggest, `B(a)(2);` is actually equivalent to `B a(2);`, so your code tries to initialize a `B` with an `int`.

To fix this, you can use C++11's uniform initialization:

```
B{a}(2);
```

Comment: Or `(B(a))(2);`

Comment: I'd avoid operator() then... Thanks a lot.

Comment: IOW: If it _looks_ like a declaration, it _is_ adeclaration. Ambiguous parses are resolved as declarations, not expressions.

Comment: [Most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) FWIW.

Comment: @YiFei: It did not look very readable here to begin with, did it? And why use operator overloading, whose sole purpose is to make code more readable, when it has the opposite effect anyway?

Comment: @ChristianHackl Yeah, sure, so I'd use some named methods. Thanks.